# Set new xml data before old xml data

Tags: php, xml, dom, rss

```
    <?php 
  if (isset($_POST['insert'])) {
    $xml = new DomDocument("1.0","UTF-8");
    $xml->load('rss.xml');
    $title = $_POST['title'];
    $image = $_POST['image'];
    $user = $_POST['user'];
    $date = date("Y/m/d");
    $indent = $_POST['indent'];
    $description = $_POST['description'];

    $rootTag = $xml->documentElement;

    $entryTag = $xml->createElement("entry");
    $titleTag = $xml->createElement("title", $title);
    $imageTag = $xml->createElement("image", $image);
    $userTag = $xml->createElement("user", $user);
    $dateTag = $xml->createElement("date", $date);
    $indentTag = $xml->createElement("indent", $indent);
    $descriptionTag = $xml->createElement("description", $description);

    $entryTag->appendChild($titleTag);
    $entryTag->appendChild($imageTag);
    $entryTag->appendChild($userTag);
    $entryTag->appendChild($dateTag);
    $entryTag->appendChild($indentTag);
    $entryTag->appendChild($descriptionTag);
    $rootTag->appendChild($entryTag);
    $xml->save('rss.xml');
  }
?>
```

I want to Insert this before the other elements can i please be helped and this coding works

This is want i want it to do:

> Old xml

```
<channel>
    <entry>
    <title>We Are Back</title>
    <image>assets/img/landscape-mountains-nature-clouds.jpg</image>
    <user>RKGaming Admin</user>
    <date>1/14/16</date>
    <indent>It's</indent>
    <description>
    our first post in the year 2016, sorry the website has been down we have been working on it trying to integrate a login system for the consumer base. We thank you for your time to wait and hope you enjoy the new updates coming from our company RKGaming in the near future. We still are looking for people to work with, so please join our ranks and sign up for the company so we can produce the game!
    </description>
    </entry>
</channel>
```

> New XML after form submition

```
<channel>
<entry>
<title>test</title>
<image>test</image>
<user>test</user>
<date>2016/03/31</date>
<indent>test</indent>
<description>test</description>
</entry>
<entry>
    <title>We Are Back</title>
    <image>assets/img/landscape-mountains-nature-clouds.jpg</image>
    <user>RKGaming Admin</user>
    <date>1/14/16</date>
    <indent>It's</indent>
    <description>
    our first post in the year 2016, sorry the website has been down we have been working on it trying to integrate a login system for the consumer base. We thank you for your time to wait and hope you enjoy the new updates coming from our company RKGaming in the near future. We still are looking for people to work with, so please join our ranks and sign up for the company so we can produce the game!
    </description>
    </entry>

</channel>
```

If you can help me with the coding for this It would really be needed so it dosnt print out the feed in the wrong way

Comment: If you place `echo gettype($xml);die();` on Line #13, does it output `object`?

Comment: Yes it dose output object

Comment: This could be useful, http://stackoverflow.com/a/30582620

Answer (score 0):

The method is called `DOMDocument::getElementsByTagName()`. It returns a `DOMNodeList`. To get the first element of a node list you use `DOMNodeList::item()`.

```
$rootTag = $xml->getElementsByTagName("roo")->item(0);
```

The root tag (document element) of an rss feed should be `rss`, not `roo`. The document element is available in the `DOMDocument::$documentElement` property, too:

```
$rootTag = $xml->documentElement;
```

Additionally `DOMNode::appendChild()` return the appended node. This allows it to combine it with the `DOMDocument::create*` method. You should not use the second argument for `DOMDocument::createElement()`. Here is a bug that can result in broken XML. Create and append text nodes:

```
$document = new DomDocument("1.0","UTF-8");
$document->appendChild($document->createElement('rss'));

$title = 'A Title';
$image = 'foo.png';
$description = 'Some text';

$rootTag = $document->documentElement;

$entryTag = $rootTag->appendChild($document->createElement("entry"));
$entryTag
  ->appendChild($document->createElement("title"))
  ->appendChild($document->createTextNode($title));
$entryTag
  ->appendChild($document->createElement("image"))
  ->appendChild($document->createTextNode($image));
$entryTag
  ->appendChild($document->createElement("description"))
  ->appendChild($document->createTextNode($description));

$document->formatOutput = TRUE;
echo $document->saveXml();
```

Output:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<rss>
  <entry>
    <title>A Title</title>
    <image>foo.png</image>
    <description>Some text</description>
  </entry>
</rss>
```